# Get integer location of True in pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to find all integer location of a True, for example I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True, False], [False, True]],
                  columns=['column0', 'column1'],
                  index=['row0', 'row1'])
```

The output should be (0, 0), (1, 1) or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get positions of `True` values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then use `zip`:

```
i, c = np.where(df)

a = list(zip(i, c))
print (a)
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.where(df))
(array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1], dtype=int64))
```